# Excel Macro Paste Special Value

Tags: vba, excel, paste

I am new to VBA and still learning, please bear with me if I'm a little slow.

I am trying to change my macro below so it will paste special value. Been googling for a while now but it won't work.

I'm using Excel 2016.

Thanks for your help in advance.

```
Private Sub Copy_Existing_Asset_Click()

    Dim i As Long
    Dim iLastRow As Long
    Dim iTarget As Long

    With Worksheets("Popcorn")

        iLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        For i = 1 To iLastRow
            If .Cells(i, "A").Value = "Capex" Then
                iTarget = iTarget + 1
                .Cells(i, "B").Copy Worksheets("Sheet7").Range("A" & iTarget + 1)
                .Cells(i, "C").Copy Worksheets("Sheet7").Range("B" & iTarget + 1)
                .Cells(i, "D").Copy Worksheets("Sheet7").Range("C" & iTarget + 1)
                .Cells(i, "E").Copy Worksheets("Sheet7").Range("D" & iTarget + 1)
                .Cells(i, "F").Copy Worksheets("Sheet7").Range("F" & iTarget + 1)
                Worksheets("Sheet7").Range("G" & iTarget + 1).Value = "Hello"
                Worksheets("Sheet7").Range("H" & iTarget + 1).Value = "How"
                Worksheets("Sheet7").Range("I" & iTarget + 1).Value = "Are"
                Worksheets("Sheet7").Range("J" & iTarget + 1).Value = "You"
                .Cells(i, "N").Copy Worksheets("Sheet7").Range("K" & iTarget + 1)
                .Cells(i, "O").Copy Worksheets("Sheet7").Range("L" & iTarget + 1)
                .Cells(i, "P").Copy Worksheets("Sheet7").Range("M" & iTarget + 1)
                .Cells(i, "Q").Copy Worksheets("Sheet7").Range("N" & iTarget + 1)
                .Cells(i, "R").Copy Worksheets("Sheet7").Range("O" & iTarget + 1)
            End If
        Next i

    End With


    With Worksheets("Chips")

        iLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        For i = 1 To iLastRow
            If .Cells(i, "A").Value = "Capex" Then
                iTarget = iTarget + 1
                .Cells(i, "B").Copy Worksheets("Sheet7").Range("A" & iTarget + 1)
                .Cells(i, "C").Copy Worksheets("Sheet7").Range("B" & iTarget + 1)
                .Cells(i, "D").Copy Worksheets("Sheet7").Range("C" & iTarget + 1)
                .Cells(i, "F").Copy Worksheets("Sheet7").Range("D" & iTarget + 1)
                .Cells(i, "G").Copy Worksheets("Sheet7").Range("F" & iTarget + 1)
                Worksheets("Sheet7").Range("G" & iTarget + 1).Value = "Hello"
                Worksheets("Sheet7").Range("H" & iTarget + 1).Value = "How"
                Worksheets("Sheet7").Range("I" & iTarget + 1).Value = "Are"
                Worksheets("Sheet7").Range("J" & iTarget + 1).Value = "You"
                .Cells(i, "R").Copy Worksheets("Sheet7").Range("K" & iTarget + 1)
                .Cells(i, "S").Copy Worksheets("Sheet7").Range("L" & iTarget + 1)
                .Cells(i, "T").Copy Worksheets("Sheet7").Range("M" & iTarget + 1)
                .Cells(i, "U").Copy Worksheets("Sheet7").Range("N" & iTarget + 1)
                .Cells(i, "V").Copy Worksheets("Sheet7").Range("O" & iTarget + 1)
            End If
        Next i

    End With


    MsgBox ("Thank You")

End Sub
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: *it won't work* is not a meaningful problem description. Please spend a few minutes reading [ask], and then come back and [edit] your post to clearly describe the problem you're having and ask a **specific** question.

Comment: okay - I need to update formula to macro above so it will paste special.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kim,

I think I understand what you asking. You wanting to know how to use the special paste features like paste values or paste formula.

It is very similar to how you are already doing it. But I want to point out one thing first, the way that you are currently doing it (`Range("A1").Copy Range("A2")`) is the best when you don't need to so a `.PasteSpecial`. Its better because it does not require the use of windows clipboard and you'll find is much faster (especially when you are copy/pasting a lot of cells)

But to do the same paste but with a paste values only use this

```
Range("A1").Copy
Range("A2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

You'll see all of the other `.PasteSpecial` options when you type in the `.PasteSpecial`. Alternatively, you can also see this website: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/xlpastetype-enumeration-excel

But just it reiterate, use the first way whenever possible to prevent your macro from bogging down from using the windows clipboard.